# Using Modulo reduction

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm really confused on how to do modular reduction. I understand we're supposed to take the factor of the exponent?

for example how would I go about doing modular reduction on:

$5^{17}$ mod 16

Comment: You don't take the factor of the exponent.  You use $c \mod m = [(a \mod m) ⋅ (b \mod m)] \mod m  $ to break the exponentiation down into workable parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that $c \mod m = [(a \mod m) ⋅ (b \mod m)] \mod m $ to divide up the problem into smaller doable parts.

First you split off an exponent to get a power of two.  So for $5^{17}$ you break it into $ 5^1 $ and $5^{16}$.  Then you split your power of two cases into progressive smaller halves until you get down to $5^2$ and the build it up from that case.

$$ \begin{align} 5^{17} \mod 16 &= (5 \mod 16)(5^{16} \mod 16) \mod 16 \\ 
& = 5(5^{8} \mod 16)(5^{8} \mod 16) \mod 16 \\
& = 5 (5^4 \mod 16)(5^4 \mod 16)(5^8 \mod 16) \\
& = 5 (5^2 \mod 16)(5^2 \mod 16)(5^4 \mod 16)(5^8 \mod 16) \mod 16 \\
& = 5 (9)(5^2 \mod 16)(5^4 \mod 16)(5^8 \mod 16) \mod 16 \\
& = 5 (9)(9)(5^4 \mod 16)(5^8 \mod 16) \\
& = 5 (1)(5^4 \mod 16)(5^8 \mod 16) \\
& = 5 (1)(1)(5^8 \mod 16) \\
& = 5 (1)(5^8 \mod 16) \\
& = 5
\end{align} $$

Comment: thank you, this cleared it up for me alot. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Also there is a number of other algorithms for on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation .  I just picked the one I knew and was easy to explain.

Comment: Where does the 9 come from? I see that before that each exponent is adding up to 17 ( for the original exponent ) but I get lost as to where the 9 came from

Comment: I calculated $25 \mod 16$ by hand.

Comment: Ohhh, ok! and then how did you get rid of the 5(9)(9) to make it 5(1)? and then for the last part you have $5(1)(5^{8} mod 16) = 5$ how did that happen as well?

Comment: I calculated $ (9 * 9) \mod 16  = 81 \mod 16 = 1 $

Comment: Alright, I got it! thanks for your help, I really appreciate it